# Why Doesn't Dividing a path by the Default Constructed path Just add a Trailing Separator in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, filesystems, filepath, trailing-slash, path-separator

Let's say that `filesystem::current_path` will return the path:

> /tmp/1567519419.773012

But I want a trailing separator. If seems like all I should have to do would be:

```
filesystem::current_path() / filesystem::path()
```

[This works on gcc](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ee633bced6236be) giving me:

> /tmp/1567519419.773012/

But on [visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio), while the `filesystem::current_path` also gives me the absolute path without a trailing seperator, dividing by `filesystem::path()` has no effect. The resulting path is still the absolute path *without* a trailing separator.

I'd like code that is cross platform compatible, and I'd like to avoid having to detect whether the current path already has a trailing separator.

Is there anything available to me?

Comment: Don't Capitalise almost Every Word In The Title. And isn't it trivial to write a function to do this?

Comment: What do `current_path()` and `path()` return?

Comment: @MarkRansom Not sure what you mean... Those are standard library functions: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path

Comment: @MarkRansom `current_path` returns an absolute path to my working directory without the trailing separator. `path` is nothing, just blank.

Comment: You say it doesn't work on Visual Studio, so you should explain what happens on Visual Studio.

Comment: @Brian Thanks for the tip. I see that was unclear. Does my edit seem clear to you?

Comment: Yes that's much better

Comment: I believe this is even the intended behavior. The examples on cppreference look like this: [std::filesystem::path::operator /=](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/append) _path("C:") / "";         // the result is "C:"     (appends, without separator)_ although, I personally think that "C:" and "C:/" is a difference but this has to mean nothing... ;-)

Comment: @Scheff Wow... that's disappointing. I guess I need to make a function to do this to get uniform behavior? Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ensure there is a trailing separator on the path. This path will be passed, as a string to another library, so I need to ensure there is exactly one trailing separator on the path.

Comment: @JonathanMee Then create the string and just normalise it standard string manipulation tools? It's trivial. I don't see the need to try to do this at the conceptual path level, unless there's something you're not telling us.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah that's what I'm thinking I have to do. I'm saddened to see that what I need to do this is only available in gcc's implementation of filesystem :( When I wrote this I assumed that the dependency was a Visual Studio bug.

Comment: The flaw is in confusing conceptual paths, with strings that abide by your string requirements

Comment: @JonathanMee So you're saying you want the [lexically normal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/lexically_normal) version of the path [plus](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/concat) a [preferred separator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path#Member_constants)?

Comment: @JaMiT Yeah. It sounds like, `filesystem::current_path() / filesystem::path()`'s behavior is platform defined. I want the gcc behavior. But to get that in a platform independent way it looks like I am responsible for writing a helper function.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I was aware that those were standard functions, just hoping that knowing the exact strings returned would provide some insight.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit since the path separator changes depending on what OS you're using, this doesn't seem like an unreasonable request.

Comment: @MarkRansom Append `std::filesystem::path::preferred_separator`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar enough with `filesystem` to know which compiler is correct (possibly both are, if there is implementation-defined behavior involved). However, the following should work on all platforms that correctly implement `filesystem`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

int main() {
    auto foo = std::filesystem::current_path();
    foo += foo.preferred_separator; // A static data member of std::filesystem::path

    // The lexically normal form eliminates doubled separators
    std::cout << foo.lexically_normal().string() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: This does exactly what I need. I can even one line it. I just can't get it to work on Visual Studio 2017 cause `lexically_normal` isn't supported :/ I'll still accept, but if you knew of another way to force normalization. It would be appreciated.